# stdin : is not in tty

Tags: command-line, ssh

I am trying to make backup from server1 to server2 by using below command in ssh

```
[user1@server1 ~]$ mysqldump -u dbuser -p"dbpwd" --opt  dbname        \
                      | gzip -c                                       \
                      | ssh  -o StrictHostKeyChecking=no              \
                             -o UserKnownHostsFile=/...../known_hosts \
                             -l deploy                                \
                             -i  /...../id_rsa                        \
                             -v  user2@server2                        \
                             "/bin/cat > /.../test.sql.gz" \
                      2>&1
```

I got the error as below

```
debug1: Sending command: /bin/cat > -t user2@server2:/..../test.sql.gz
stdin: is not a tty
/bin/cat: user20@server2:/..../test.sql.gz
debug1: client_input_channel_req: channel 0 rtype exit-status reply 0
debug1: client_input_channel_req: channel 0 rtype eow@openssh.com reply 0
: No such file or directory
debug1: channel 0: free: client-session, nchannels 1
debug1: fd 0 clearing O_NONBLOCK
Transferred: sent 265040, received 2552 bytes, in 0.0 seconds
Bytes per second: sent 6736670.0, received 64865.6
debug1: Exit status 1
mysqldump: Got errno 32 on write
```

can any one resolve this issue?

**Updation**

I removed 'user2@server2' and 'deploy -i' from backup command and run it. It gives me below messages

```
debug1: Sending env LANG = en_US.UTF-8
debug1: Sending command: /bin/cat > -t /....../test.sql.gz
stdin: is not a tty
debug1: client_input_channel_req: channel 0 rtype exit-status reply 0
debug1: client_input_channel_req: channel 0 rtype eow@openssh.com reply 0
/bin/cat: /......./test.sql.gz: No such file or directory
debug1: channel 0: free: client-session, nchannels 1
debug1: fd 0 clearing O_NONBLOCK
Transferred: sent 248608, received 2536 bytes, in 0.1 seconds
Bytes per second: sent 4628197.5, received 47211.3
debug1: Exit status 1
mysqldump: Got errno 32 on write
```

Comment: I do not think the `user2@server2:` should be there before the path.

Comment: @dudu: i chacked without this but it gave me same error.

Comment: @GhostAnswer what do you mean by `ssh -l deploy user2@server`? both the `-l <user>` and the `<user>@` notation do more or less the same...

Comment: I removed "user2@server2" but gives me same bug

Comment: @GhostAnswer please update the error-message after you removed the `user2@server2`; and try removing the `-l deploy` argument

Comment: @umlaute: check my updates.

Comment: i think @StephaneChazelas is correct, and your remote user has weird settings for it's shell; find out login-shell the remote user uses and check its configuration.

Comment: That seems like a really complex way to write `mysqldump --host db_host`

Comment: It says `/bin/cat > -t /....../test.sql.gz`, so you're not telling us the truth about what command you run.

Answer (score 3):

If the login shell of the remote user (`user2` on `server2`) is `bash`, beware that `bash` reads and interprets `~/.bashrc` (and possibly `/etc/bash.bashrc` or the equivalent on the remote system) when called over `ssh`, even when not interactive (as in when it just interprets that `/bin/cat > user2@server2:/......./test.sql.gz` that you give it).

Make sure that things in `~/.bashrc` don't do things like `stty` or `mesg` (the `mesg` from [`sysvinit-utils`](http://savannah.nongnu.org/projects/sysvinit) as found in many Linux distributions is known to output that exactly same message as you can see by running `: | mesg n`), or only do it after having checked that stdin is a terminal `[ -t 0 ]` and that the shell is interactive (`case $- in (*i*) ...;; esac`).

If the login shell of the remote user is `csh` or `tcsh`, look at the `.cshrc` and `.tcshrc` and for `zsh` at `~/.zshenv` which are interpreted by every shell including non-interactive ones regardless of whether they're called over `ssh` or not (but as such, they will typically not do things with the `tty` unconditionally).

Note that that will not cause your command to fail, just that spurious message to be displayed.

What would cause the command to fail though is:

```
 /bin/cat > user2@server2:/......./test.sql.gz
```

When does not make much sense unless there is a directory called `user2@server2:` in the home directory of `user2` on `server2`.

That's probably what causes the error:

```
 : No such file or directory
```

The fact that the "file or directory" it's complaining about appear to be "empty" suggests there is a carriage return character hidden somewhere in the command line.

What you want is `/bin/cat > /path/to/output/file/on/server2/test.sql.gz`, and the `/path/to/output/file/on/server2` directory  must exist beforehand.

You may also want to remove the `-v` and the `~/.bashrc` temporarily as at the moment, we're seeing messages from `ssh`, from commands run in your `~/.bashrc`, possibly by the remote shell when it interprets that `cat ...` command line, by `cat` and by the `mysqldump` command which makes it difficult to see what's what.

Comment: can you explain me how I used this in my backup command?

Comment: @GhostAnswer, you use `ssh` in your command, that `ssh` runs the remote user's login shell on the remote machine to interpret that command line. And if that  shell is bash, it will interpret that `~/.bashrc` on the remote machine which most probably has a `mesg n` somewhere in it. Remove that `mesg n`, or change it to `mesg n 2> /dev/null` or as I said, sanitize your `~/.bashrc` so that bash only does those things when called interactively.

Comment: I am newbie for this so can you please update my command which I can run on my server1's ssh. and make the backup on server2 in perticular directory

Comment: @GhostAnswer, what you (probably) need to do is fix your `~/.bashrc` on `server2` which is broken. Maybe you can include it in the question so we can help you on that.

Comment: once check my updates and tell me

Comment: @GhostAnswer since we cannot read your mind nor the configuration on your computer, you have to tell us

Comment: @GhostAnswer, `~/.bashrc` is a configuration file of the user, not something that is affected by software updates. But as I said your issue is probably somewhere else not in that "not a tty" message.